# React Router Webpack 2 Code Splitting - Using getChildRoutes()

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-2, code-splitting

When I navigate to `/home` I have a navbar that shows a home icon, about, settings, etc. The component that displays this navbar lives inside `HomeContainer`. Based on the url, I want to load `HomeContainer`'s routes. I'm using wepback 2, code splitting, react router 3.

Here is my routes file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Portal from './components/portal/Portal';

const componentRoutes = {
  component: App,
  path: '/',
  indexRoute: { component: Portal },
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/login/Login')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/homepage/HomeContainer')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      },
      getIndexRoute(partialNextState, callback) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          callback(null, {
            component: require('./components/homepage/Home'),
          })
        })
      },
      getChildRoutes(partialNextState, callback) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          callback(null, [
            require('./components/homepage/About').default
          ])
        })
      }
    }
  ]
};

const Routes = () => {
  return <Router history={hashHistory} routes={componentRoutes} />
};

export default Routes;
```

Problem is, how do I get the `about` component to render? I want to be able to navigate to `/home/about` and for it to load, as a child route of `HomeContainer`.

Comment: checkout this blog - https://medium.com/prod-io/code-splitting-in-react-using-webpack-1aa1014da216

Answer (score 0):

```
getChildRoutes(partialNextState, callback) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
          callback(null, [{
               path: 'about',
               component: require('./components/homepage/About').default
            }            
          ])
        })
}]
```

Comment: you might consider adding some explanation